# If all finite subsets of a set have at most rank W, does the set itself necessarily have at most rank W?

Tags: logic, set-theory, ordinals

In other words, if no finite subset of a set has a rank greater than some ordinal, does the set itself have the same rank upper bound?

My proof sketch for yes is:

Assume the set S is non-empty and has no greatest rank element(trivial otherwise). Then the rank of S is a limit ordinal X which is the least ordinal greater than all members of S.

If the rank of any finite subset of S is at most V < X then since W is a limit ordinal there is an ordinal Y between V and X.

Either there is a subset of S with rank Y (contradiction), or Y is greater in rank than all members of S (also contradiction)

Does this work?

Comment: Is W just any limit ordinal, or is it $\omega$? Also, please make your question body self-contained.

Comment: Any limit ordinal. And sorry what do you mean by self-contained? As in have the title question in the body too?

Comment: I see. And yes, that's what I mean. I would be a good idea to use $\rm\LaTeX$, by the way, which will both improve the readability and help you use Greek letters (e.g. `\delta` for $\delta$) to make sure people don't mistake W to be $\omega$.

Comment: Ah ok apologies, edited now. Will brush up on the LATEX but have edited it to contain hopefully less confusing variables names for now

Answer (score 1):

> Either there is a subset of S with rank Y (contradiction), or Y is greater in rank than all members of S (also contradiction)

It looks to me like there is a step missing here (also, I suppose you mean "finite subset"?).

You can argue as follows. Let the rank of any finite subset of $S$ be not greater than some ordinal $\alpha$. Then in particular this holds for singleton subsets $\{x\}\subseteq S$. Now using the recursive definition of rank,

$$
rank(S)=\sup\{rank(x)+1\mid x\in S\}=\sup\{rank(\{x\})\mid x\in S\}\le\alpha.
$$

Comment: Thanks! That’s much more concise. Re: missing step, perhaps I spelt it out badly but the gist is basically - if the rank of any finite subset is at most V and the rank of S is the least ordinal X > V (by definition), then since there must be an ordinal Y between X and V (because it’s a limit ordinal), X can’t be the rank of S